# Simplification of $x\exp(x)-\exp(x)+x-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I have this expression $x\exp(x)-\exp(x)+x-1$.

In my long equation. My question is: is there any way to express this term with simplified mathematical terms, like $\sinh$ or any other function.

$$x\exp(x)-\exp(x)+x-1$$

Comment: You probably could. You could also factor: $(\exp(x)+1)(x-1)$

Comment: I don't think there's anything you can do other than factoring it.

Answer (score 3):

$$xe^x - e^x + x - 1$$

$$= e^x(x - 1) + (x - 1)$$

$$= (x - 1)(e^x + 1)$$